# Lambda function syntax in python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I came across the `sorted()` example below and cannot figure out why `lambda student: student[2]` can represent a function specifying the integers in the tuple.

Can anyone lay out the mechanics or a clearer example of how python knows the lambda function student should pull data from `student_tuples`?

```
student_tuples = [
        ('john', 'A', 15),
        ('jane', 'B', 12),
        ('dave', 'B', 10)]

sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])   # sort by age
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Comment: `a = lambda student: student[2]` is the same as `def a(student): return student[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lambda student: student[2]
```

clearer:

```
lambda x: x[2]
```

A lambda expression returns a function. The arguments for this function are before the ':' and separated by commas.

```
lambda x,y: x + y
```

The function does not have a name. But you can imagine as if lambda creates an abstract function. The lambda expression returns a function.
(Lambda is kind of essence of what a function is).
You can give lambda expressions also a name:

```
f = lambda x: x[2]
```

And now you can use the name to call the function.

```
f(["a", "b", "c"]) ## returns "c" because the list element "c" has index 2

list(map(f, student_tuples))
## [15, 12, 10]
```

or with the lambda expression:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[2], student_tuples))
## [15, 12, 10]
```

is actually what happens inside of sort:
the lambda-function is applied to each element of the list (`map`).
The outer `list()` around `map()` is necessary to execute `map`, because `map` is lazily evaluated (a promise to execute it but not yet executed).
Lazy evaluation is actually a nesting of lambdas ... well, lambdas are the core of functional programming. Programming languages like Lisp make you clear what lambda actually is. (You can also google for lambda calculus).

In R, a functional language, in such case the order of the iterable object indexes is determined and then applied on the object - for the ordering/sorting - to achieve the final sorted version (function `sort`)

I guess, sth similar is going on inside Python's `sorted` function.

Comment: Very thorough explanation Gwang-Jin. Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome, Daniel! Thank you for choosing! Learning a functional language, especially any Lisp language helps a lot to understand `lambda`. Python's lambda is unhappily restricted to one-liners. (well, one can define a named function outside of lambda and then just apply this function inside the lambda expression ...). But lambda actually helps to understand that any function is actually a lambda-object assigned to a name (function-name). The anonymous lambda-expression can also be regarded as a name for the function. (A name which contains the instruction of what a function should do - magic!)

Answer (score 1):

`lambda student: student[2]` is equivalent to the following function, aside from not having a name:

```
def <anonymous function>(student):
  return student[2]
```

The reason why it winds up pulling from `student_tuples` is because the `sorted()` function passes each individual element from its first argument (the sequence to sort) to its `key` argument (a function that takes an element and returns the corresponding sort key). As such, `sorted()` passes each element of `student_tuples` to the lambda function in turn, during which the value of the element is temporarily assigned to the `student` variable.